# If rows exist in table then return value from table ELSE return a default value. - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, union-all

I have to write a query which will return the latest timestamp column's value from a table if rows exist.

If there is no row(s) in table then it return the default value.

I have write the following query in MS-SQL which is working fine for me.

```
IF Exists (select * from employees)
      Begin
           select  TOP 1  timestamp from employees order by timestamp desc;
      End
Else
      Begin
            select '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as timestamp;
      End
```

But , now I need to write this query in MySQL.

I have tried a-lot of methods but no luck.

**In MySQL:**

```
IF (select EXISTS (select * from employees)) 
    BEGIN
           select  timestamp from employees order by timestamp desc LIMIT 1
      END
ELSE
      BEGIN
            select '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as timestamp
      END
```

Can anyone please comment how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT timestamp FROM employees ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
FROM DUAL -- you may remove FROM DUAL if MySql's version is 8.0+
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employees)
```

or, if `timestamp` is not nullable:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(timestamp), '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') AS timestamp
FROM employees;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YJkJyyJU).

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer. Your both solutions worked for me.
Demo is also amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Is the below sql meet your demand?

```
select IF(timestamp IS NOT NULL,timestamp,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') as `timestamp` 
       from employees order by timestamp desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You have put the NOT NULL check & it didn't worked when there is no data available in the table.  Please check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

*For these types of queries, you can use CASE statements in MY-SQL*

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN e.timestamp IS NOT NULL 
        THEN e.timestamp
    ELSE '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
END AS 'timestamp_col'
FROM employees AS e
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Because you have put the NOT NULL check & it didn't worked when there is no data available in the table.  Please check the accepted answer.